# c++ property undeclared variable

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I am doing the get, put property for C++ and get stuck at a point.

This is my code :

Header file:

```
class Battery {
    public:
        __declspec (property (put = SetCharge, get = GetCharge)) int Charge;
    private:
        int _charge;
};
```

And cpp file:

```
int GetCharge() {
    return _charge;
}

void SetCharge(int charge) {
    _charge = charge;
}
```

I got the error saying that _charge is undeclared variable.

I really don't understand why! Can someone help me out?

Comment: Not done c++ in a while, but it looks like you're missing the class scoping in your .cpp. I think you need `int Battery::GetCharge()...` otherwise it's accurate, you've not declared it in that function.

Comment: Instead of learning non-standard C++, better get a grip on C++. This MS specific thing is not used, even on Visual C++ by Windows programmers.

Comment: @Ajay this is not standard C++? I found this online and my netbean working ok on it :-?. So is there a way to actually make a property like c# or I have to separate them into 2 different method?

Comment: NetBeans is not a compiler, it is an IDE. Check which compiler is running in background.

Comment: @Ajay I believe that is GNU. In it I found Xcode file

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx

Comment: @Ajay that's the place I got the idea of __declspec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct your .cpp file this way:

```
int Battery::GetCharge() {
    return _charge;
}

void Battery::SetCharge(int charge) {
    _charge = charge;
}
```

Comment: I have done this at the beginning. But then I tried to find a way to shorten the class to be as same as C# so I came with this __declspec!

Answer (score 2):

I thing you don't conect the two functions with your class. Is two ways to do this, the one is at the first anser and the second is to do it inline as:

```
class Battery {
    public:
        int Battery GetCharge() {return _charge;}
        void Battery::SetCharge(int charge) { _charge=charge;}
    private:
        int _charge;
};
```

I thing this working...

Answer (score 0):

Along with defining the two functions using the scope resolution operator, you should also include GetCharge and SetCharge in your class definition:

```
class Battery {
    public:
        __declspec (property (put = SetCharge, get = GetCharge)) int Charge;
        int GetCharge();
        void SetCharge(int charge);
    private:
        int _charge;
};
```